# Show that the set $\{\frac{1}{n^2}: n \in N \} \cup \{0\}$ is closed

Tags: analysis

I want to show that $Y=\{\frac{1}{n^2}: n \in N \} \cup \{0\}$ is closed.

I think I can do so by arguing that $Y$ contains its upper and lower bounds, $1$ and $0$, and hence is closed. But I think I might need to argue that $Y^c$ is open, which implies that $Y$ is closed.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Changed. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not enough to show that $Y$ contains its upper and lower bounds: $[0,1)\cup(2,3]$ contains its upper and lower bounds but is not closed. Show instead that its complement is open; you can actually write the complement explicitly as a union of pairwise disjoint open intervals (counting open rays as open intervals).

Comment: Like this: $(0, \frac{1}{n^2})$ $\cup ... \cup$ $(\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{4}) \cup (\frac{1}{4},1)$?

Comment: @kbball: Not quite: that first interval contains too much (e.g., $\frac1{(n+1)^2}$), and you also need the rays $(\leftarrow,0)$ and $(1,\to)$, and you need to find a way to indicate that you’re taking the union of **all** intervals of that form: $$(\leftarrow,0)\cup\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\left(\frac1{(n+1)^2},\frac1{n^2}\right)\cup(1,\to)\;.$$

Comment: Is there some reason to do it this way rather than just say that $Y$ contains its only limit point, $0$?

Comment: @kbball: In order to prove rigorously that $0$ is the only limit point of $Y$, you have to show that every point not in $Y$ has an open nbhd disjoint from $Y$, which means showing that $\Bbb R\setminus Y$ is open. Why not just do the latter directly and forget about the extra work of dealing with limit points?

Comment: @kbball: You’re welcome!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Well, one needn't do that. If $y$ is a limit point of $Y$ we know there must exist a sequence of points $\langle y_n\rangle$ in $Y$ such that $y_n\neq y$ and $y_n\to y$. Since $Y$ is itself the range of a nonrepeating convergent sequence, things work pretty nicely.

Comment: @Pedro: Yes, you can do it that way, but writing it out rigorously is more work than writing down the complement: if you don’t want deal with open sets, you pretty much have to show that every injective sequence in $Y$ has a subsequence that is a subsequence of $\left\langle\frac1{n^2}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$, which is not really hard but is notationally a bit messy.

Answer (score 4):

What is the only limit point of $Y$? Is it contained in $Y$?

Comment: It does. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I looked up the definition and you are right.